# Why is my $.inArray() function not working in voting system?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb, meteor

I want to allow users to upvote/downvote post only once, so I want to check whether user voted already or not. But the problem is that my function always says that user voted already, without single userId in voted array in the MongoDB. Here is the function :

```
Template.postItem.events({
    'click': function() {
        Session.set("selected_post", this._id);
    },

    'click a.yes': function(event) {
        if (Meteor.user()) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if ($.inArray(Meteor.userId(), Posts.voted)) {
                console.log('User already voted.');
            } else {
                var postId = Session.get('selected_post');
                console.log("voting" + Meteor.userId());
                Posts.update(postId, {$push: {voted: Meteor.userId()}});
                Posts.update(postId, {$inc: {'score' : 1}});
                }
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`inArray` is a **very** poorly-named function: It returns the index at which the thing was found, or -1 if it wasn't found, **not** (as the name suggests) `true` if found, `false` if not. So you want

```
if ($.inArray(Meteor.userId(), Posts.voted) !== -1) {
// ----------------------------------------^^^^^^^
```

Comment: `inArray is a very poorly named function` indeed :(

Comment: They should have named it to something like `indexInArray` or something.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer: Yeah. The usual name is `indexOf`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder which is so mainstream that they should just do an update and phase this out.

Comment: @Mouser Ya *but* quoting John Resig: `Well, we can't really change the inArray method now, to return a boolean, without causing serious backwards-breaking changes. We're going to have to live with the name as-is, unfortunately.

As to the second point, it's moot: We already replace jQuery.inArray before the function is ever called, with the native indexOf implementation`